# What class and method to use while reading/writing a file to internal/external storage android?

Tags: android

I have google alot, read javadoc, plus search different forums including this reading the issue but not found the correct answer to my question. The code snippet below is working fine but I want to exactly know what function to use exactly for read/write file in android. One can write to internal storage using OutputStream, FileOutputSteam.write(), Other is to use OutputStreamWriter(FileOutputSteam).write(), further BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter).write(), and finally PrintWriter.write().

Same goes for the InputStream case whether to use InputStream, FileInputSteam.read(), InputSreamReader(FileInputStream).read(), BufferedReader(InputStreamReader).

I want to know which exactly is the best proper way to do it. Please help me out as totally confused with this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
private static final String FILENAME = "students.txt";
private EditText stdId;
private Button Insert;
private Button Search;
private Button Update;
private Button Delete;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName(); //output: com.fyp2.testapp.MainActivity

    //value used for insert/delete/search
    stdId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTxtId);

    //insert value in application sandbox file
    Insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);
    Insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            String IdToInsert = stdId.getText().toString().trim();
            if(IdToInsert.length() > 0) {
                myInsertFunc(IdToInsert);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Id cannot be null!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                stdId.requestFocus();
            }   
        }
    });

    //search value from application sandbox file
    Search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    Search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            String IdToSearch = stdId.getText().toString().trim();
            if(IdToSearch.length() > 0) {
                mySearchFunc(IdToSearch);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Id cannot be null!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                stdId.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });


    //delete value from application sandbox file
    Delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    Delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            String IdToDelete = stdId.getText().toString().trim();
            if(IdToDelete.length() > 0) {
                myDeleteFunc(IdToDelete);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Id cannot be null!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                stdId.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
}

//function to insert
private void myInsertFunc(String data) {
    //If student id already exist don't write it again -> Not handled at the moment
    //Other exceptions may not have been handled properly
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND));
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
        bufferedWriter.append(data);
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Student ID: " + data + " Inserted Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    } 
}

//function to search
private void mySearchFunc(String data) {
    //Id id not found show toast to user -> Not handled at the moment
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(FILENAME);

        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if(receiveString.contains(data))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Found Student ID: " + data , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }
}

private void myDeleteFunc(String data) {
    /* I have found a solution to delete a specific line from the file.
     * But the problem is that it needs to scan the whole file line by line and copy the file contents that not matches the string to temp file.
     * This solution can reduce the effeciency. Consider search 20,000 records in a file.
     * Need to work around on it.
     */
}

private void myUpdateFunc(String data) {
    /* Same goes to the update process...
     * Need to scan all records and copy content in temp file and put the updated data in that file.
     * Need to work around on this issue too...
     */
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

They all serve a purpose. There is best proper way, because each writer was made for a reason.  Usually anything that has buffered is more efficient if you have mulitple read/writes/flush.

Both the Android and Java docs can be helpful and java docs give you more description for these writers. Check out these documentation. Try reading the javase6 ones which are more detailed:

[Android_FileWriter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html)

[Java_FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

[Android_OutputStreamWriter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html)

[Java_OutputStreamWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html)

[Android_BufferedWriter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)

[Java_BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)